# Is there a way to set certain nodes within a SLURM partition to be preferred over other nodes?

Tags: partition, hpc, slurm, sbatch

I have a cluster that consists of mostly CPU+GPU nodes with a couple of CPU only nodes. At the moment they are in two partitions, *'gpuNodes'* and *'cpuNodes'*, respectively. Our needs are growing and our CPU only jobs are needing to use the CPU+GPU nodes in addition to the CPU only nodes to complete in a timely fashion. I was thinking of creating an *'all'* partition that has the nodes from both of the previous nodes. Ideally, I'd like to fill out the CPU only nodes before going onto submit jobs to the CPU+GPU nodes.

This leads me to my question. Is there a way to set a priority/preference for a set of nodes within a partition so that a batch job assigned to the partition fills out the preferred nodes first? Or, if you know of a better way to accomplish my goals, I'm not set on the *'all'* partition mentioned above.

If it helps name schema for my nodes follow the syntax below:
Nodes with CPUs + GPUs: gn001-gn100
Nodes with CPUs only: n001-n20

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically done with the `weight` parameter in `slurm.conf`

From the [slurm.conf man page](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html#OPT_Weight):

> All things being equal, jobs will be allocated the nodes with the lowest weight which satisfies their requirements.

In your case you would set something like

```
NodeName=n[001-200] ... Weight=10
NodeName=gn[001-100] ... Weight=100
```

Jobs that do not request GPUs will be allocated the CPU-only nodes first, and only if there a no CPU-only node, will they be allocated CPU+GPU nodes. Jobs that request GPUs will of course only be allocated CPU+GPU nodes.